# mapping columns automatically to data conversion task and OLDB Destination

Tags: ssis

In the data flow task, I have used the `OLDB Source`, `Data Conversion Transformation`,  and `OLDB Destination`.

The problem is that I have more than 100+ columns to be mapped to the data conversion and then back to `OLDB dest` as well.

Is there a way that the columns are mapped automatically to the data conversion task with the output alias name updated as 
`<Column Name> (Converted)` instead of `Copy of <Column name>` (which comes by default).

Then mapped back again from `<Column Name> (Converted)`  to the dest. table.
The naming convention of the source column is different than the target table.

For e.g:

1.

```
Source Column : WM - Order Overage Amount
Target Column : WMOrderOverageAmount
```

2.

```
Source Column : Show Std__D_S_ on Sales Inv_
Target Column : ShowStdDSonSalesInv
```

Comment: As far as I know so far, they cannot be automatically mapped

Comment: Maybe with BiML, you could check.

Comment: What data conversion are you performing? Are you converting from unicode (nvarchar) to standard (varchar)? You can do this in the source query. You could do a search and replace on the source query to come up with a query that converts it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

For data conversion there is no auto mapping
For destination mapping you an auto map by names.

There are two ways of reducing the effort:

1. Use [Derived Column] transformation instead on [Data Conversion]
   And use the property for replace and give the new names as the destination table to the columns
2. Modify the output column names in the source editor (you can do this at columns tab)